# How to prevent nz-select from expanding width inside ng-zorro table?

Tags: html, css, angular, antd, ng-zorro-antd

I use nz-select inside the ng-zorro table. Initially, I set the 25% as the width for all column in the table. However, when I select the color, as the name of the color is too long, it expands the color column and it is no longer width 25%.

How can I prevent the color column from expanding and remain as 25% width after I choose the color from the selection dropdown?

I also attached the html and ts file below.

**Initially**

[image]

**After choose color**

[image]

```
<nz-table #basicTable [nzData]="listOfData">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th nzWidth="25%" >Name</th>
      <th nzWidth="25%">Age</th>
      <th nzWidth="25%">Color <br> (Choose 3)</th>
      <th nzWidth="25%">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of basicTable.data">
      <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.age }}</td>
      <td>
      <nz-select style="width: 100%" nzMode="multiple" nzPlaceHolder="Select Colors">
      <nz-option *ngFor="let option of colorOption" [nzLabel]="option" [nzValue]="option">
      </nz-option>
    </nz-select>
    </td>
      <td>
        <a>Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</nz-table>
```

---

```
listOfData: Person[] = [
{
  key: '1',
  name: 'John Brown',
  age: 32,
  address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park'
},
{
  key: '2',
  name: 'Jim Green',
  age: 42,
  address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park'
},
{
  key: '3',
  name: 'Joe Black',
  age: 32,
  address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park'
}
];

colorOption = [
  "Option Color Number 1",
  "Option Color Number 2",
  "Option Color Number 3",
  "Option Color Number 4",
  "Option Color Number 5",
  "Option Color Number 6",
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
  <nz-select style="width: 100%" nzMode="multiple" nzPlaceHolder="Select Colors" appSelectWidth>
                <nz-option *ngFor="let option of colorOption" [nzLabel]="option" [nzValue]="option">
                </nz-option>
            </nz-select>
```

```
import {AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef, OnInit, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[appSelectWidth]'
})
export class SelectWidthDirective implements AfterViewInit {

    constructor(private ElementRef: ElementRef, private Render2: Renderer2) {
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            const {width} = this.ElementRef.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
            console.log(width);
            this.Render2.setStyle(this.ElementRef.nativeElement, 'width', width + 'px')
        }, 200)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so easy to prevent nz-select from expanding width inside ng-zorro table
you must add nz-select width style in 'px'

like this

```
<nz-table #basicTable [nzData]="listOfData">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th nzWidth="25%" >Name</th>
      <th nzWidth="25%">Age</th>
      <th nzWidth="25%">Color <br> (Choose 3)</th>
      <th nzWidth="25%">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of basicTable.data">
      <td>{{ data.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ data.age }}</td>
      <td>
      <nz-select style="width: 100px" nzMode="multiple" nzPlaceHolder="Select Colors">
      <nz-option *ngFor="let option of colorOption" [nzLabel]="option" [nzValue]="option">
      </nz-option>
    </nz-select>
    </td>
      <td>
        <a>Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</nz-table>
```

check [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-trscdz)